Rollingover the logs for short-lived java application with logback
I have developed an Java Springboot application for one of my batch processing tasks. I will be using the jar of that application with a shell script. Shell script will be executed either manually or via some application and the shell script will execute the jar with some similar command like below.
java -cp /pathToDir/myapp.jar

This execution is not a time consuming process which will only take few minutes. I am using logback as my logging framework for this Java app and I am using a logback.xml to configure. I have added a rolling policy to rollover the log in every day (Similar to below).
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

But it simply not happening as each time the app is running, it will use the existing log file. As it is short lived app, logging event will not cause any file rolling. I searched for any solutions but couldn't find any. Just seeking for a solution which can resolve this issue.

I suggest omitting the file attribute. This will ensure that the newly created log file will have the desired date.
Also, you should probably try the simpler TimeBasedRollingPolicy instead of SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.
Depending on the size of the log files, totalSizeCap might be helpful as well.
